# Trying to copy and paste some data to another sheet and the code "object required" keeps showing up

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am new to using Excel VBA and keep getting the object requires error. I am trying to copy some data from one sheet and past it to another and save. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot

Here is my code

```
Sub cp()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Range("F4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet8").Select
    emptyrow = Sheet8.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(erow, 1).Select
    'Range("B2").Select
    'ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Typo in your code `Cells(erow, 1).Select` should probably be `Cells(emptyrow, 1).Select`

Comment: Use of `Option Explicit` will prevent you from making such typographical errors in the future...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to copy range "F4" from "Sheet1" to the row below the last row of data on "Sheet8". If so, I would use this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F4").Copy 
Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A:" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

If you don't need paste special you could be more direct:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F4").Copy Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A:" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
```

To save, assuming your code is in the workbook you want to save, use this at the end of your code:

```
Thisworkbook.Save
```

If it is in a different workbook use this at the end of your code:

```
Workbooks("xxx").Save
```

Where "xxx" is the name of the workbook.